# How to make typescript declaration file work for function types

Tags: typescript, type-declaration

This is my code:

**tsconfig.js**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "target": "es6",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "declaration": true,                   
    "strict": true,                          
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types",
      "./@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@types/*": ["@types/*"]
    },
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./*", "@types"]
}
```

**@types/index.d.ts**

```js
interface Person {
  is: boolean;
  str: string;
}

type doThing = (is: boolean) => boolean;
```

**example.ts**

```js
const jon: Person = {
  is: 'hello world'
}

const doThing = x => `${x}`;
```

in example.js:

- The interface for 'Person' is found and works
- The type for 'doThing' is not found

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only sure way is to create a type which is named differently, but can be used onto any function.

**index.d.ts**

```js
type TdoThing = (is: boolean) => boolean;
```

**example.d.ts**

```js
const doThing: TdoThing = x => `${x}`;

const doOtherThing: TdoThing = x => `${x}`;
```